# EC2 Auto Scaling scale-up event while Code deploy process going on

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am using CodeDeploy with AutoScaling and would like to know if there is a way to ensure that newly created instances due to scale-up event  would receive the application version (latest) deployed on the older instances that where running during the deployment.

The new instances were launched while CodeDeploy was in the process of deploying application code to the deployment group.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the autoscaling group as a target in code deploy. In order to make sure that new instances launched in autoscaling group have latest application version, I've created a lambda function which you can add as a stage in codepipeline once your application is successfully deployed on your target autoscaling group. you can find lambda function here.

https://github.com/matesio/AWSLambdaAMILC